# No puedo abrir archivos .py .pyw ni .exe desde botones creados en una ventana

Tags: python, botón

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox
from tkinter import filedialog
import sqlite3
# IMPORTO LAS LIBRERIAS NECESARIAS PARA CREAR LA VENTANA, LA BARRA DE TAREAS Y LOS BOTONES

miRaiz=Tk()   
miRaiz.geometry("1400x700")
miRaiz.title("GESTION  AGROPECUARIA")

miFrame=Frame(miRaiz)

miFrame.pack()

# CREO LA FUNCION QUE CREO QUE ABRIRIA EL ARCHIVO DESEADO

def abreArchivoAgricultura():
    archivo=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Abrir")

botonAgricultura=Button(miFrame, text="Agricultura", width=20, command = abreArchivoAgricultura)
botonAgricultura.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

miRaiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te sugiero que leas [ask] para saber como formular una pregúnta, es necesario mas alla de tu código especifiques cual es tu problema, y de ser posible cuál es tu resultado esperado.

Answer (score -1):

No puedo comentar, así que comento desde aquí:

Tu pregunta al parecer es que no puedes abrir archivos de Python, si eso sucede con todos los archivos Py, deberías verificar tu instalación de Python, que este agregado al Path y las extensiones estén asociadas al interprete...

Corrección:

Edita la función de abrir el archivo así:

```
def abreArchivoAgricultura():
    import os
    archivo=filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Abrir")  
    os.system(f'python {archivo}')
```

Comment: quizá no me exprese claramente, desde una ventana con un botón necesito abrir, mediante ese botón, otras ventanas que no son mas que otros archivos .py.